# How to secure a HTTPS .m4v URL using Apple Transport Security

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, plist, app-transport-security

I am using a single https static URL in my iOS application. I want to secure that using ATS. I am confused which exception should be used in .plist file.

1-NSIncludesSubdomains
2-NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads
3-NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy
4-NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion
5-NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads
6-NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy
7-NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add any flags in ATS to enable secure communication. ATS flags are used to exclude domains from requiring `https` communication.

Make sure your url you use starts with `https` and it will connect securely.

Now, there are more advanced things you can do, such as certificate pinning, but that doesn't involve ATS, and I'd recommend using something like Alamofire to help do all that configuration properly.